# A word for achieving 2 qualities considered contradictory to one another

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests, history

Is there a word for a method of achieving 2 objectives or having 2 qualities that are typically considered to be in conflict with or contradictory to one another?

By qualities I mean strong/ fast, anything like that. For example if a musician wanted his performance/piece to have variation and continuity, you would have to make a compromise/ happy medium between the two, unless you could find a method of not having to compromise and instead have an optimal amount of both.

Comment: would 'bridged the gap' get what you're after?  I'm still confused with your headline use of "qualities" vs the bodies 'achieving 2 objectives'.

Comment: Yes bridging the gap is what im after essentially but in a word. By qualities I mean strong/ fast, anything like that. For example if a musician wanted his performance/ piece to have variation and continuity, you would have to make a compromise/ happy medium between the two, unless you could find a method of not having to compromise and instead have an omptimal ammount of both.

Comment: There are words like 'meld' or 'merge' that could help but they imply turning two into one(which I hear 'synthesis' to do). I believe you are talking about perhaps "intertwining" two together so they connect but maintain their individuality?  1) But do you want to also suggest that something is "solved" 2) contradictory?: None of these(merge, or intertwine) suggest the ideas are necessary contradictory either.. merely distinct.

Comment: "married" might work.  'The interlude married the "spritely theme" with the ominous undertone present throughout the piece.'

Answer (score 3):

At the heart of Hegel's philosophy is the reconciliation of two contradictory ideas -- thesis and antithesis -- by means of the [**Hegelian dialectic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectic), the result being **synthesis**.

OD:

> [**synthesis**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synthesis): (in Hegelian philosophy) *the final stage in the
>   process of dialectical reasoning, in which **a new idea resolves the
>   conflict between thesis and antithesis*** [emphasis added]
>
> Example sentences:
>
> - ‘It is also to be noted that the dialectical process is not simply from thesis and antithesis to final **synthesis**; it is an eternal,
>     open-ended spiral of development.’
> - ‘Every **synthesis** becomes a new thesis, which becomes the target of a new antithesis.’

Comment: A downvote? Really? I'd love to know why, and to hear your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I'll give you an Up to make up for the down.  What makes the request really difficult is that, the body is in conflict with the title.  The title doesn't say anything about 'achieving two objectives'  .  That would be my guess why they down-voted it.  It could also be a greater emphasis on choosing words that will be understood correctly on top of having the definition technically correct.  (that would have been my reason for staying neutral)

Comment: @Tom22 Thanks. On rereading the question, I can see that it could have been posed better. I'm still annoyed though. :-) My answer addresses the body of the question well, IMHO.

Comment: Sorry missed out part of the title I was meant to write, has been edited now.

Answer (score 0):

**Accommodation** :
1. The act of accommodating or the state of being accommodated; adjustment.
2. Something that meets a need; a convenience.
3. Reconciliation or settlement of opposing views.

Answer (score -1):

From your comments I would suggest ***marry*** or **married**

- it strongly suggests two distinct entities
- in our modern sense of the word, the term means united while remaining individual essences intact .
- unfortunately it might not suggest 'contradictory'.. (although they do say opposites attract ; )  )

'The interlude married the "spritely theme" with the ominous undertone present throughout the piece.'

> ***married***
>   [mar-eed]
>
> [from dictionary.com married](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/married)
>   adjective
>
> 1.
>   united in wedlock; wedded:
>   married couples.
>
> 2.
>   of or relating to marriage or married persons; connubial; conjugal:
>   married happiness.
>
> 3.
>   (of an antique) **created from components of two or more authentic pieces**.
>
> 4.
>   **interconnected or joined; united.**
>
> 5.
>   (of a family name) acquired through marriage.